# Is there a way to monitor a windows process or a network port and trigger an action?

Tags: mysql, database, windows, postgresql

Would it be possible to create some sort of trigger on the client side when an application he is using is connecting to a database?

I am trying to monitor when the application makes changes to the database and send some api response to another app.  Is there any app that would do this?

I cannot edit the application nor the database to create triggers.

*EDIT* the database is not on the client computer but on another server. I cannot do any modification to the database server. I am looking for a client side solution if possible.

Comment: Which "database" are you talking about?

Comment: In my case postgresql but I am interested in any other db

Comment: A solution to this will depend completely on the DBMS product being used.

Comment: The database is on another server, I am looking for a client side solution. Why would the DBMS matter?

Comment: For Postgres you wouldn't need to create triggers: you could hook into logical replication and a decoder plugin - can be implemented without changing the database tables or creating triggers. But this sounds more as if you are asking for a library that does all that for you - however, those question are off-topic here. The client side also depends on the programming language and how you talk to the database. E.g. in Java/JDBC you could use a wrapped JDBC driver that simply logs all statements.